# How to decompose unitary representations of compact groups in terms of irreducible representations?

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

I am following Folland's *A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis*, currently looking at unitary representations of compact groups (Chapter 5).

Let $\rho$ be a unitary representation of compact $G$ on $\mathcal{H}_{\rho}$, and
$[\pi],[\pi']\in\hat{G}$.

From Proposition 5.3, we know that for an invariant subspace $M_{\pi}$ of representation space $\mathcal{H}_{\rho}, M_\pi'$ is the orthogonal complement of $M_\pi$ if $\pi$ and $\pi$ are not unitarily equivalent.

Then a note after this proposition says we can write the space $H_\rho$ as a direct sum of $M_\pi$ over the representatives of the equivalence classes $[\pi]$.

But, since $M_\pi'$ is the orthogonal complement of $M_\pi$, do we not have $H_\rho$ as a direct sum of $M_\pi$ and $M_\pi'$ only?

While $\rho$ might have more than two non-unitarily equivalent subspaces, it does not seem possible (or sensible) to write $\rho$ as a direct sum over all of them given that the entire representation space of it can be expressed using only one of these invariant substances, via a direct sum of the subspace and its orthogonal complement?

I hope my question is clear. Thanks.

Comment: I think your understanding of Prop 5.3 is not correct.  I'd go over it again more carefully.

Comment: The proposition you cite simply says $M_\pi$ and $M_{\pi'}$ are orthogonal, not that they are orthogonal *complements*...